# Http Inbound Gateway takes 2x timeout to send timeout response to client

Tags: spring-integration

We're using an http inbound gateway to process http requests. Lately , we wanted to set specific http response code that will be sent to user after a timeout. 
We upgraded to `spring 4.2.1` and set

> the reply-timeout-status-code-expression attribute

and it's working now.

But there is a problem : if we set the timeout to 10 seconds , a `ReplyTimeoutException` is raised in the web application after exactly 10 seconds but the response arrives to the client after 20 seconds ( exactly the double ).

We changed the timeout several times but it always take 2x timeout for the response to be received by client.

This is the xml config for the http inbound gateway :

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundRequest" request-channel="inbound-channel" 
         supported-methods="POST" path="/Request" error-channel="errorChannel" reply-channel="gateway_response"
        reply-timeout="5000" request-payload-type="java.lang.String" reply-timeout-status-code-expression="'504'" >
```

A Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have an `error-channel` - if the error flow returns no response, the reply timer starts again when the error flow ends (we're waiting for a reply from the error flow).

Instead of returning nothing from the error flow, you need to throw a `MessageTimeoutException`.

Turning on DEBUG logging and following the message flow is the best way to diagnose issues like this.

If that's not the problem, you need to show the rest of your configuration (edit the question, don't try to post it in a comment).

Comment: I removed the error-channel because I don't need to process any specific exception and it works fine now. Thanks. Not sure I understood why the reply timer starts again, could you please explain a bit more or send me a link to documentation. Thanks a lot.